# How to tokenize the string with and without delimiter in single split

Tags: java, string, tokenize

Assume i have a single string content as follows

```
Input:
  FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'
  FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC'
  FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'
  PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'  
  SOUZA?:GB?:GB'
  FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'
Expected Output:
  Number of segments: 4

Input:
  FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'
  FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'
  PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'  
  FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'
Expected Output:
  Number of segments: 3
```

Basically i want to consider as same line when the delimiter ' comes with a question mark. The line delimiter is '

How to tokenize and get the count the segments in Java ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Java Programmer can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: why do you expect 3 segements in 2nd example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind in a regex:

```
String input = "FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'\n"
    + "  FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC'\n"
    + "  FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'\n"
    + "  PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'  \n"
    + "  SOUZA?:GB?:GB'\n"
    + "  FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'";

String[] tokens = input.split("(?<!\\?)'\\s*");
System.out.println(tokens.length);
```

> 4

But, in the second example I would expect two segments, not three...

Comment: /MyClass.java:10: error: illegal escape character
String[] tokens = input.split("(?<!\\?)'\s*");
                                         ^
1 error

Comment: @Gaspar, fixed.

Comment: In the second example i expect three instead of two..So this doesn't works for me..Please help me with an example which works for both

Comment: if it's the "same line when the delimiter ' comes with a question mark," then you have two segments there; otherwise you may want to review and/or rephrase your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the above - but again demonstrating that the second example you post may be wrong because the third line ends with a `?'` which, by your definition should not be a break.

```
public void test() {
    test("FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'" +
            "FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC'" +
            "FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'" +
            "PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'" +
            "SOUZA?:GB?:GB'" +
            "FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'");
    test("FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'" +
            "FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'" +
            "PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'" +
            "FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'");
}

private void test(String s) {
    String[] split = s.split("(?<!\\?)'");
    System.out.println(split.length+"->"+Arrays.toString(split));
}
```

prints

> 4->[FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC, FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC, FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'SOUZA?:GB?:GB, FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC]
>
> 2->[FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC, FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC]

Comment: This gives a wrong output as 5 when i add one more string in between. example   String input = "FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'" +
                "FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC'" +
                "FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'" +
                "PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'" +
                "SOUZA?:GB?:GB'" +
                "SOUZA?:GB?:GB'" +
                "FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'";

Comment: @JavaProgrammer But that *should* be `5`. There are `5` parts because of the `4` splits `UTC'`, `UTC'`, `GB'`, `GB'`

Answer (score 0):

I think what he/she want is this:

```
String a = "FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC'"
        + "FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC'"
        + "FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??'"
        + "PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??'  "
        + "SOUZA?:GB?:GB'"
        + "FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC'";
String result[] = a.split("'");
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result));
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    if (!stringList.get(i).startsWith("FTX") && i != 0) {
        stringList.set(i-1, stringList.get(i-1) + stringList.get(i));
        stringList.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < stringList.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(stringList.get(j));
}
```

> FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC
>   FTX+BBB+++201707141009UTC
>   FTX+CCC+++201707141009UTC?:??PISCO US LTS;?:V.D??  SOUZA?:GB?:GB
>   FTX+ZZZ+++201707141009UTC